# Partitioning a set into its convex components

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and call the maximally convex subsets of $X$ (ordered by inclusion $\subseteq$) the *convex components* of $X$.

I was wondering if, in possible analogy to the case of connected components, any such set $X$ is necessarily the union of its convex components?

Comment: Connected components are disjoint, while your convex components usually aren't. I don't know if term "component" should be used here. But $X$ must be sum of such convex sets due to simple fact, that at every point $x\in X$ you could just look at $\subseteq$ maximal convex set containing $x$, and it will be "convex component"

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74153/what-is-the-name-for-a-maximal-convex-set-of-points-contained-in-another-set-of/4741872#4741872

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering if, in possible analogy to the case of connected components, any such set $X$ is necessarily the union of its convex components?

Of course it is a union of its convex components. That's because any point $x\in X$ is convex, and thus contained in some convex component.

The interesting question would be: is it necessarilly the **disjoint** union of its convex components? The answer is no. Here's a simple counterexample: consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with:

$$C_1=[0,1]\times\{0\}$$
$$C_2=\{0\}\times[0,1]$$
$$X=C_1\cup C_2$$

Note that both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are convex components of $X$ (and these are all there are) by your definition. However $C_1\cap C_2=\{(0,0)\}$ is nonempty. So $X$ is not a disjoint union of its convex components.

Answer (score 1):

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-functional-analysis/volume-6/issue-3/Convex-components-and-multi-slices-in-real-topological-vector-spaces/10.15352/afa/06-3-7.full), a maximal convex set of a subset $S$ of a real topological vector space $X$ is called a *convex component* of $S$. The paper also gives the following sufficient condition for the convex components of $S$ to form a partition.

> **Theorem 2.10.** Let $X$ be a real topological vector space. Let $M$ be a countable disjoint union of convex subsets of $X$ which are closed in $M$. Then the convex components of $M$ are exactly those closed convex sets.